# Iterating through json kv pairs using jq

Tags: json, bash, for-loop, scripting, jq

I've been trying this for a bit now. I want to loop through all the keys that I pulled out and now want to get the values by looping through those keys in bash.
What I'm trying to do is basically:

I got keys through

`keys=$(echo "$tags" | jq -r 'keys[]')` where $tags is a json output
The json which is stored in $tags is

```
{
      "project": "en.wikipedia",
      "article": "Talking_Heads_discography",
      "granularity": "daily",
      "timestamp": "2021092800",
      "access": "all-access",
      "agent": "all-agents",
      "views": 381
    }
```

Now I wanted to loop through all the keys and get the values for further processing. I wanted to do something like

```
for key in $keys; do
    value=$(echo $tags | jq -r .[key])
    echo "$key has value $value"
done
```

Is there an easy way to pass a variable to jq to get the key value
These are the things I tried to pass the variable

```
for key in $keys; do value=$(echo $tags | jq -r '.[key]'); echo "$key has value $value";done
for key in $keys; do value=$(echo $tags | jq -r '."$key"'); echo "$key has value $value";done
for key in $keys; do value=$(echo $tags | jq -r '."[key]"'); echo "$key has value $value";done
for key in $keys; do value=$(echo $tags | jq -r '.[key]'); echo "$key has value $value";done
for key in $keys;do value=$(echo $tags | jq -r '.[key]'); echo $value;done
for key in $keys;do value=$(echo $tags | jq '.[] | ."$key"' ); echo $value;done
```

I wanted to do this in bash scripting only

Comment: [edit] your question to show the output of `echo "$tags"` (i.e. the input to the tool you want to write) and the final expected output given that input.

Comment: Use the `--arg` option to pass values into jq (something like `jq --arg k "$key" '.[$k]' <<< "$json"`). However, with jq being a very powerful language, consider doing it the other way round, i.e. shifting your logic into jq, so you'd be iterating and processing all in there. All with just one call to jq.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "$tags" |jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) has value \(.value)"'
project has value en.wikipedia
article has value Talking_Heads_discography
granularity has value daily
timestamp has value 2021092800
access has value all-access
agent has value all-agents
views has value 381
```

**UPDATE**

variant @pmf from comment

```
for key in $keys; do value=$(echo $tags | jq --arg k "$key" -r '.[$k]'); echo "$key has value $value";done
```

but he's not fast

it is better to do it through an *associative array*

```
declare -A v
eval $(echo "$tags" |jq -r 'to_entries[]| "v[\(.key)]=\"\(.value)\";"')
for key in $keys; do echo "$key has value ${v[$key]}";done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I wanted to store key and values in different variables to process/use them later

Answer (score 0):

The following illustrates one approach:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[][]' | while read -r key ; do
    read -r value
    echo "key=$key and value=$value"
done
```